# Wrong return value in FromObjectDictionary method

Tags: servicestack-text

I noticed in ServiceStack.Text\PlatformExtensions.cs file that FromObjectDictionary method could return a wrong value.

```
    public static object FromObjectDictionary(this IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> values, Type type)
    {
        if (values == null)
            return null;

        var alreadyDict = type == typeof(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>);
        if (alreadyDict)
            return true;

        var to = type.CreateInstance();

        PopulateInstanceInternal(values, to, type);

        return to;
    }
```

If alreadyDict is true I think that it should return values object. Anyway true value seems wrong and could cause an invalid cast exception.

I don't know if writing here is the right procedure to submit issues in ServiceStack.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for catching this! I've resolved this issue with `FromObjectDictionary()` in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/f24e7a1ec91192228359894796ff85ebefaebdf2).

This change is available from v5.4.1 that's now [available from MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).